# svn co "revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included"

Tags: svn

I have this error from a user, this user can up but no commit. All others user can commit, up, etc.

Error message:

> Checkout from
>   svn+ssh://user@192.168.1.5:/svn/project,
>   revision HEAD, Fully recursive,
>   Externals included To better debug SSH
>   connection problems, remove the -q
>   option from 'ssh' in the  [tunnels]
>   section of your Subversion
>   configuration file. Network connection
>   closed unexpectedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should find out if it is a problem of his computer or his account.

Try if the user can ssh onto the server where svn resides.

I´d try the same commands for that user on a different computer.

If it works there, diagnose the user´s computer: disk errors, time skew, firewall, installation etc.

If it doesnt work there - hard to tell because I have no idea how your svn is configured, and how authentication is being handled. Can you give us more details?